# Using jQuery.ajax() to access c# WebMethod results in 'Unknown Web Method'

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first attempt at using jQuery.ajax() to call a WebMethod. I have searched and searched stackoverflow, as well as Google I don't know how many times, and at this point I feel I'm just trying random fixes I find, hoping something works. I've certainly stopped learning, so I thought it time to ask.

My error: Unknown web method Date. Parameter name: methodName.

My class and WebMethod:

```
[ScriptService]
public partial class _Maps : Page
{

    protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string Date()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

my page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="Scripts/cSharp.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="clickArea" style="height: 1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#clickArea").click(function ()
    {
        alert("Clicked");
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Maps.aspx/Date',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#clickArea").text(msg.d);
                },
                error: function(xhr, msg, msg2)
                {
                    alert(msg2);
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but I have limited experience with the technologies I'm using, and I know I must be missing something silly. I've been at this almost all day, and I feel I am just running in circles now. I can post more information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried doing something like return Json(DateTime.Now.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Same issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, finally!

All I needed to do was set the Inherits property of my .ASPX page in the page declaration. It could not find the method, as the code behind was not my actual page that has my WebMethod. Silly, like I had thought.

Comment: could u please explain more how did u do that?